# How to make narrator correctly treat groups in NavigationView

Tags: c#, uwp, accessibility, uwp-xaml

I have simple navigation view:

```
<NavigationView>
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Home"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Customers"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Orders"/>
        <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
        <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Reports"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Customers"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Orders"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Sales"/>
        <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
        <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Sales Charts"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Customer"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Product"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Time"/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <ContentFrame/>
</NavigationView>
```

You can see there are groups defined using `NavigationViewItemHeader` and `NavigationViewItemSeparator`. Narrator does not take account of this and reads all items as if they were flat members of the same collection. I cannot group these items in `<Grid>` or `<StackPanel>` (as recommended in msft docs), as `NavigationView` does not render such items at all.

How I can achieve good results without manually creating automation peers and specifying my own groups?

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't much you can do without wrapping them (which you said doesn't work, might work on the WInUI 2 one though) or creating an AutomationPeer since the NavigationView automationpeer treats each of them as a separate item (as they are). If you need more granual control over this (having groups etc), [hierarchical NavigationViewItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem.menuitemssource?view=winui-2.5) might be a good workaround/solution